# SharePoint 2010 Setting Max Versions on Existing List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I've got a SP2010 list that's had no cap limit set to the versions. I want to reduce the number of versions kept to 10 so I set the "Keep the following number of versions" option to 10. It looks like SP doesn't go ahead and remove all the extra versions on the list items.  For example, a list item has 24 versions - still has 24 versions after making this change.

What's the best way to clean up a list and remove all versions over the past 10 versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older existing versions are not automatically cleaned up for existing items / documents when setting a version limit on a list or library. It is only enforced when the next update is performed in a document / list item.

You could use PowerShell to iterate all items in the list / library and perform an update on each item. If you don't want the update to appear in the version history itself, use the [`SystemUpdate($false)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate?view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_SPListItem_SystemUpdate_System_Boolean_) method.

Answer (score 1):

If a list limits the number of major versions, the earliest versions are deleted when the limit is reached.

Here is detailed information about SharePoint versions for your reference:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/saantil/archive/2010/12/04/sharepoint-versions-explained.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint automation probably doesn't want to make the choice for you about which 10 versions to keep (i.e., most recent 10 versions? specific versions?). If you were to get it to 9 versions, then test your created limit, does it work then? I suspect it would drop the oldest version from that point forward. Can you give that a try and let us know? I'm curious. :)

Comment: Your answer would have best been a comment. It has been my experience that when you limit the number of items on a new list, SP retains the most recent versions therefore dropping the older versions beyond the set limit. This has always worked without issue.  My question is what happens when you set the limit on an existing list with many versions. I may have found my own answer though. If you set the limit to 10 for example and the edit an existing item with 50 versions, SP removes the 40 oldest versions at that time, leaving the 10 most recent versions.

Comment: My apologies. This was my first comment/answer thing... tres noob.